# How do I retain selected option in a select list with a for loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop

I created a list of countries using the ACF Wordpress plugin. The plugin allows for creation custom post meta fields so each post got an additional meta data namely the country name.

I get the country list with a WP_Query and store it in the `$result` variable:

```
$myquery = new WP_Query($myargs);
if ($myquery -> have_posts()) :
    while ($myquery -> have_posts()) : 
        $myquery -> the_post();
        array_push($arr, get_field('country'));
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
$result = array_unique($arr);
```

What I would now need is to pick a country and then retain it when the search for the posts with that country meta field returns. (The blue button to the right.)

How do I go about it? So far I’ve tried this:

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" class="form-control">
<?php 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) : 
    $selected = (isset($_POST['countries']) && $result[$i] == $_POST['countries']) ? 'selected' : ''; 
    $selected = ($result[$i] == @$_POST['countries']) ? 'selected' : ''; 
    echo '<option value="' . $result[$i] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $result[$i] . '</option>'; 
endfor; 
?>
</select>
```

Which will not retain the country selected. Neither will

```
<?php 
    $selected = (isset($_GET['country']) && $result[$i] == $_GET['country']) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; 
?>
```

On top of this I need to add the ‘all’ value to allow to select all countries: `<option value="all">all</option>`. The ‘all’ value will have to retain too.

BTW could anybody explain the need for `$_POST` here for me please? I don’t believe there is a need for a `<form>…</form>` for this app.

The app can be found at http://elanonimo.dp.ua/ Please ignore the green dropdown button.
(The complete WP theme source code is at http://www.filedropper.com/package1467207510)

Comment: The line with `$selected = ($result[$i]` does not add anything

Comment: For improved readability, consider only using `<?php` at the beginning of your php code and `?>` at the end instead of for each line.

Comment: For improved readablity, consider using (correct) indentation (leading spaces when inside a loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_unique($arr)` does not reindex the keys of the array, so the `for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)` loop does not work. You can either

```
$result = array_values(array_unique($arr));
```

or

```
foreach ($result as $country) {
    $selected = (isset($_GET['countries']) && $country == $_GET['countries']) ? ' selected' : ''; 
    echo '<option value="' . $country . '"' . $selected . '>' . $country . '</option>', "\n";
}
```

Working code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fuy5-6f3c

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. Thank you for your effort and time. It sure added to my knowledge.

Comment: Just to notice that you put the `<select>` name to the `$_GET`. I believe that should be the variable name that is `$selected = (isset($_GET['country']) && $country == $_GET['country']) ? ' selected' : '';`

Comment: Try to split your problem in small parts and experiment before jumping into false conclusions like about checkboxess not included in field. Maybe this can inspire HTTP://phpfiddle.org/main/code/smu7-rxf4

Answer (score 0):

To add the ‘all’ value to allow to select all countries: all. 
Just add an initialisation statement:

```
$myquery = new WP_Query();
if ($myquery -> have_posts()) {
  $arr = ['All']; // statement added
  while ($myquery -> have_posts()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

> BTW could anybody explain the need for $_POST here for me please? I don’t believe there is a need for a `<form>…</form>` for this app.

`$_POST['countries']` will get initialized in php if the server receives an HTTP POST request from the browser. The traditional way to do this is by having a `form` with your a countries field in it and a submit button with a method="post". However, in your page, the input button is not in a form but it works. This means there is some javascript somewhere that attaches a `click` event handler (that does the get request) to the `input`.

However, in your page, there is no `<form>`. There is a javascript somewhere that attaches an event to the input button. It uses POST, not GET. It also posts a country as we can see from the `http://elanonimo.dp.ua/?num=off&country=%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F&price=` url.
If you want to use that country in php, you should use `$_GET['country']`

If `$_GET['country']` does not work, there may be an encoding issue. Try it with a standard ASCII country name.

Comment: There is indeed a javascript portion of the code which acts upon the blue button click. The full code displays when you right click on the page and select view source.

Comment: `if (selectedCountry != '') {
    location.href = 'http://elanonimo.dp.ua/?num=' + num + '&country=' + selectedCountry + '&price=' + a;
   } else {
    location.href = 'http://elanonimo.dp.ua/?country=all&num=' + num + '&price=' + a;
   }`

Comment: OK, that is how selectedCountry is converted to country in your URL. Also location.href performs a GET, so use $_GET['country']``, not `$_POST['countries']`. Do you understand the encoding issue? Did you try ASCII countries like `Italy` instead of `Италия`?

Comment: I got what you meant by the possible encoding issue. Will try and use the ASCII country name now.

Comment: Changing `Италия` to `Italy` didn't seem to help. Smth is wrong with the code I use. `<select name="countries" id="countries" class="form-control">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) : ?>
 <?php $selected = (isset($_GET['country']) && $result[$i] == $_GET['country']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>
 <?php echo '<option value="' . $result[$i] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $result[$i] . '</option>'; ?>
 <?php endfor; ?>
</select>` Sorry can't properly format the comments.

Comment: Try to improve your debugging: print_r(variables), in browser look at html source code and look at network in Developer Tools. Reduce your environment. Tell us what you tried, exactly what you saw.